# Apse divides central orbit into symmetrical portions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion

I am solving dynamics and unable to digest author's views regarding apse. Help from the community is needed.

```
Theorem :- If the central acceleration p is a single valued function of the distance, 
every apse line divides the orbit into equal and symmetrical portions
```

Author's goes on to prove the below result

> v<sup>2</sup> = C - ∫ Pdr

{v - velocity ,
P - central acceleration ,
r - radial distance of particle assumed to be moving under the effect of central acceleration P ,
pole of the acceleration lies on origin}

Author states that since acceleration and velocity are single valued for r , they are same for same value of r.Hence the direction of motion is independent[understood and agreed].

So if the motion of the particle is reversed at a particular apse , it will trace a symmetrical orbital path on the other side of apsidal distance.[not understood]

**I accept that the particle upon changing the direction of motion will trace the same path from where it has arrived , it nowhere leads to the central orbit being symmetrical about the apse.**

[image]

Suppose particle is at apse 1 , going towards apse 2 in clockwise direction ,if the direction at apse 1 is reversed , particle will go towards apse 2 in anticlockwise direction , but nowhere the path is symmetrical

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse the velocity vector of an object $O$ at any point in its orbit then you have essentially just reversed time (since the central force has no dependence on velocity or time). So a new object $O’$ that is identical to $O$ apart from its reversed initial velocity will retrace the orbit of $O$ in reverse.

At an [apsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis) the velocity vector is perpendicular to a plane through $O$ and the centre of attraction, so the future paths of $O$ and $O’$ are mirror images in this plane. As $O’$ retraces the path of $O$ then $O$ will trace the mirror image of this path as it completes its orbit. So the orbit of $O$ is symmetric.

Comment: Sir, i have added an image . Nowhere it seems still that path will be symmetrical. It will retrace its own path for sure but not sure about its symmetry.

Comment: @HarshVardhanSingh Read the second paragraph of my answer carefully. $O'$ retraces the path of $O$; at the same time $O$ traces out a path that is a mirror image of the path of $O'$.